# catch pressing back button in Next 13 app router

Tags: next.js13, app-router

I would need to catch pressing back button in browser and show modal to alert user, that he has unsaved changes on page. Normally I would use **window.onbeforeunload** or in react with react-router i was using **use_unstableBlocker**. Has **app router** something similar? Because of soft navigation window.onbeforeunload is not working and **popstate** event is not enough because url change already when alert is shown on popstate.

I was trying to have this on the top of page.tsx to not caching page:

`export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic', revalidate = 0`

or this in next.config.js:

```
        headers: () => [{
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: [
            {
                key: 'Cache-Control',
                value: 'no-store, max-age=0',
            },
        ]
    }],
    output: 'standalone',
    generateEtags: false,
```

but nothing works to me.

So is there any other way to catch pressing prev/next button in browser or to force hard-navigation on pressing prev/next button in browser?

Comment: Having the same question